# Spatial join with concatenation of results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-join, concatenation

I've two polygon layers which I would make a spatial join.
The objective is to transport a specific code from layer A (Municipality) to layer B (Issues) using like a concatenate function, in this way I'll have in the layer B a field with the codes provided from the layer A. For instance if I've two polygon of A intersecting the same polygon on B I'll have a code like "A.B".
The problem is that ArcGIS with "spatial join" make this work but don't separate the value eg:**AB instead A.B**.
[image]

[image]

Some suggestions?

Comment: Can U plz add some screen shot

Comment: Please **edit the question** to contain graphics showing the attributes of the two tables and the exact details of the procedure you're using.

Comment: Intersect A and B. Summarise result using B id taking first and last attributes from A